# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 6: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, bluetooth

I'm coding with Python on Raspberry pi 2.

I'm trying to send several orders to two devices by bluetooth at the same time but it doesn't work.

According to the error message, when I send an order to the second device, I can't decode the response. I already tried to encode with 'UTF-8' but it didn't work either...

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bluetooth-master/Bluetooth-master/rfcommcli.py", line 60, in <module>
    StartBTClient()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bluetooth-master/Bluetooth-master/rfcommcli.py", line 54, in StartBTClient
    print('reception 2 : ', rec2.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 6: unexpected end of data
```

So can you help me, please.

Here is the code :

```
import bluetooth


class BT(object):

    address_2 = ('00:04:3E:93:39:A9')
    address_1 = ('00:04:3E:6A:10:A9')

    def __init__(self):
        self.btSocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

    def __exit__(self):
        self.Disconnect()

    def Connect(self, mac, port=1):
        self.btSocket.connect((mac, port))
        print('Connecter')

    def Disconnect(self):
        try:
            self.btSocket.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

    def Send(self, data):
        self.btSocket.send(data.encode())

    def Receive(self, size=1024):
        return self.btSocket.recv(size)


def StartBTClient():
    cli = BT()
    print('BT1 Connexion en cours ...')
    #cli.Discover()
    cli.Connect(cli.address_1, 0o01)

    cli2 = BT()
    print('BT2 Connexion en cours ...')
    #cli.Discover()
    cli2.Connect(cli2.address_2, 0o02)
    print('Donner un ordre ... (ordre shutter)')

    while True:
        data = input()
        if (data == 'exit'):
            break
        cli.Send("read\r")
        cli2.Send("read\r")
        rec = cli.Receive()
        rec2 = cli2.Receive()
        print('reception 1 : ', rec.decode())
        print('reception 2 : ', rec2.decode())

    cli.Disconnect()
    cli2.Disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StartBTClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently device #2 is responding with some, but not all, of the bytes of a UTF-8 encoded value.

You need to ensure that you have received and assembled all of the bytes of the message before you attempt to decode them. This may involve calling `.recv()` multiple times.

Comment: Following your idea, I tried this : <code> self.btSocket.recv(size, socket.MSG_WAITALL) </code> but It doesn't work. (same error message)